# Stopping php returning the same result multiple times

Tags: php, sql

[image]I am trying to display a list of friends using PHP and SQL, and my code partially works. However, it is returning the same result on multiple occasions and I would like it not to.

The SQL:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT ubuser.usr_firstname, ubuser.usr_lastname, ubuser.usr_DOB,  
ubuser2_1.usr_firstname & \" \" & ubuser2_1.usr_lastname 
AS UBFriend, ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1, ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2, ubuser.usr_ID, 
ubuser2_1.usr_ID 
FROM ubuser 
AS ubuser2_1 
INNER JOIN (ubFriendsLink INNER JOIN ubuser ON ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1 = ubuser.usr_ID)
ON ubuser2_1.usr_ID = ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2 
WHERE (((ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1) = ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] .")) 
OR (((ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2) = ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] ."))";
```

The SQL works (or seems to).

The code for displaying the result:

```
 <?php
$nrecs=0;
while (!$FriendsRs->EOF) { 
$nrecs++;   
?>
<? php 
    if (.$SESSION['usr_ID'] == ['ub_lnkID1'])
   {
  echo <p>Name: <?php echo $FriendsRs->Fields['UBFriend']->Value ?><br/ >
  <? php 
  else
  echo <p>Name: <?php echo $FriendsRs->Fields['usr_firstname']->Value ?> <?php 
  echo $FriendsRs->Fields['usr_lastname']->Value ?><br />
<?php $FriendsRs->MoveNext() ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The result:

```
Name: Carl Smith
Name: Rob Sanderson
Name: Rob Sanderson
Name: Tony Jackson
```

The problem seems to be that what I am getting is a list of the names associated with the ub_lnkIDs, where i only want to display the individual names. (FYI, Rob Sanderson is not needed, but it can be returned once).

**EDIT:**

The desired output is

```
Name: Carl Smith
Name: Tony Jackson
```

Comment: Its not clear, give an example of  your desired output

Comment: My apologies, the desired output should be: Name: Carl Smith Name: Tony Jackson

Comment: @RobSanderson No, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20952153/edit) your question and add it there.

Comment: you say the sql seems to work, have you tried it in the sql workbench or phpmyadmin to verify the problem isn't with the structure of your query?

Comment: i see there is no closing for the while loop ..

Comment: The sql has been tested as working in access (with the usual tweaks of course)

Comment: The while loop closes at record set EOF.

Comment: so if i understand the question right...you don't want the person who is using the system's name to be displayed? why use an if/else then? just have an if like if (.$SESSION['usr_ID'] != ['ub_lnkID1'])

Comment: it would also be helpful to know what the tables look like

Comment: The user who has the session id can be displayed, but only needs to be displayed once. I shall attempt to post the tables (new at this, please bear with me!) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've described it sounds like you want to remove the duplicates from your list.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the session check but your original if/else condition didn't make sense so I changed it to what might be right based on your query.

```
<?php

   $Arrnames = array();

// Produces array containing all the names in the correct format
while (!$FriendsRs->EOF) 
{
    if ($SESSION['usr_ID'] == $FriendsRs->Fields['ub_lnkID1'])
    {
        array_push($Arrnames, "<p>Name: ".$FriendsRs->Fields['UBFriend']->Value."<br />");
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($Arrnames, "<p>Name: ".$FriendsRs->Fields['usr_firstname']->Value ." ". $FriendsRs->Fields['usr_lastname']->Value . "<br />");
    }
    $FriendsRs->MoveNext();
}

// Removes the duplicates from the array
$ArrnamesDedupped = array_unique($Arrnames);

// Loops the de-duplicated array and echos the result
foreach ($ArrnamesDedupped as $value)
{
  echo $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I have tried this but am getting the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in H:\STUDENT\S0213628\part2\friendslist.php on line 64...Line 64 is the line if ($_SESSION['usr_ID'] == ['ub_lnkID1'])

Comment: The issue with the if ($SESSION['usr_ID'] == ['ub_lnkID1']) was that it should be prefixed with the object eg $FriendsRs->Fields[''ub_lnkID1''].  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (.$SESSION['usr_ID'] == ['ub_lnkID1'])
```

My best guess is the single `=` is causing your if statement to fail

`==` means is the same as (and can return false) WHEREAS `=` will always return true! (`=` is used for setting values.)

Additionally you open `<?php` tags above the if statement - and then open them again in your `<?php echo` without closing them?

```
<? php 
if (.$SESSION['usr_ID'] = ['ub_lnkID1'])
{
echo <p>Name: <?php echo //HERE
```

Comment: I've already tried that and there is no difference, but thankyou anyway :)

Comment: No Problem - update the shown code so no-one else suggests that as a fix.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems.e.g. opening
      php tags inside php tags,  no closing } for the if clause,  html paragraphs (p) opened and not closed etc.

what I think you want to do (not tested):

```
<?php
$nrecs = 0;
while (!$FriendsRs->EOF) {
    $nrecs++;
    if ($SESSION['usr_ID'] !='ub_lnkID1') {
        echo "<p>Name:" . $FriendsRs->Fields['usr_firstname']->Value . " " .    $FriendsRs->Fields['usr_lastname']->Value . "</p>";
    }
    $FriendsRs->MoveNext();
}
?>
```